# Authentication is failing for fresh installation of Pentaho on Linux

Tags: java, tomcat, pentaho

I have just done a fresh installation of the latest version of Pentaho on ARCH LINUX and setup JRE 1.7 and set all environment settings & paths etc.

Initially the engine would not start with an error about being unable to start a listener, so I needed to comment out the listener in listeners.xml

```
<!--<bean id="backingRepositoryLifecycleManagerSystemListener" class="org.pentaho.platform.repository2.unified.BackingRepositoryLifecycleManagerSystemListener"/>-->
```

Now the engine starts up and I can access the console via port 8080, however none of the default users / passwords work and it always errors with:
    "A Login Error Occurred, Please Try Again".

Looking at the log files I see a several warnings / errors but nothing that seems to indicate what may be preventing authentication.

No new logs are generated upon each failed login attempt.

Any suggestions on how I can track down the problem ?

## Edit - Anonymous Access

By following these instructions: http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fsecurity_guide%2Ftask_removing_security.html - I was able to access the console with the file, view and help menus and the main panel, but nothing is displayed in the working panel.

If I click File > New > CDF Dashboard, or Jpivot View, I get a dialog saying "Just a few Moments Please" but when that closes the working panel is still blank.

Edit 2 - Earlier Version
I unstalled 5.01 and it immediatly worked straight out of the box, so it looks like something may be broken in the latest release.

### Summary of catalina.out log:

```
Aug 22, 2015 10:51:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
Aug 22, 2015 10:51:18 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Aug 22, 2015 10:51:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 329 ms
Aug 22, 2015 10:51:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 22, 2015 10:51:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.43
Aug 22, 2015 10:51:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor pentaho.xml
[Server@26dee1]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) entered
[Server@26dee1]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) exited
[Server@26dee1]: Initiating startup sequence...
[Server@26dee1]: Server socket opened successfully in 1 ms.
[Server@26dee1]: Database [index=0, id=0, db=file:../../data/hsqldb/sampledata, alias=sampledata] opened sucessfully in 322 ms.
[Server@26dee1]: Database [index=1, id=1, db=file:../../data/hsqldb/hibernate, alias=hibernate] opened sucessfully in 10 ms.
[Server@26dee1]: Database [index=2, id=2, db=file:../../data/hsqldb/quartz, alias=quartz] opened sucessfully in 12 ms.
[Server@26dee1]: Startup sequence completed in 345 ms.
[Server@26dee1]: 2015-08-22 10:51:20.140 HSQLDB server 1.8.0 is online
[Server@26dee1]: To close normally, connect and execute SHUTDOWN SQL
[Server@26dee1]: From command line, use [Ctrl]+[C] to abort abruptly
10:51:30,440 ERROR [GuavaCachePoolPentahoJcrSessionFactory] Error obtaining session from cache. Creating one directly instead: javax.jcr.SimpleCredentials@1ea9919
10:51:30,680 ERROR [Logger] misc-org.pentaho.platform.plugin.action.defaultcontent.DefaultContentSystemListener: User not found; nested exception is org.springframework.security.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException: User not found
10:51:30,730 ERROR [ActionAdapterQuartzJob] ActionAdapterQuartzJob.ERROR_0004 - Action "org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.versionchecker.VersionCheckerAction" failed to run as a quartz job
10:51:30,731 ERROR [ActionAdapterQuartzJob] ActionAdapterQuartzJob.ERROR_0001 - Property "ActionAdapterQuartzJob-ActionClass" or "ActionAdapterQuartzJob-ActionId" must be set in the job data map
10:51:30,731 ERROR [ActionAdapterQuartzJob] ActionAdapterQuartzJob.ERROR_0002 - Failed to create an instance of action "unknown"
10:51:30,821 ERROR [FileHandler] Couldn't find or create CDE .  dir
10:51:30,824 ERROR [CdeEngine] Couldn't find or create CDE base dir.
10:51:30,824 ERROR [FileHandler] Couldn't find or create CDE components  dir
10:51:30,826 ERROR [CdeEngine] Couldn't find or create CDE components dir.
10:51:30,826 ERROR [FileHandler] Couldn't find or create CDE styles  dir
10:51:30,827 ERROR [CdeEngine] Couldn't find or create CDE styles dir.
10:51:30,827 ERROR [FileHandler] Couldn't find or create CDE templates  dir
10:51:30,828 ERROR [CdeEngine] Couldn't find or create CDE templates dir.
10:51:30,828 ERROR [FileHandler] Couldn't find or create CDE widgets  dir
10:51:30,829 ERROR [CdeEngine] Couldn't find or create CDE widgets dir.
10:51:30,829 ERROR [FileHandler] Couldn't find or create CDE .  dir
10:51:30,830 ERROR [CdeEngine] Couldn't find or create CDE base dir.
10:51:30,831 ERROR [FileHandler] Couldn't find or create CDE components  dir
10:51:30,831 ERROR [CdeEngine] Couldn't find or create CDE components dir.
10:51:30,832 ERROR [FileHandler] Couldn't find or create CDE styles  dir
10:51:30,833 ERROR [CdeEngine] Couldn't find or create CDE styles dir.
10:51:30,835 ERROR [FileHandler] Couldn't find or create CDE templates  dir
10:51:30,836 ERROR [CdeEngine] Couldn't find or create CDE templates dir.
10:51:30,836 ERROR [FileHandler] Couldn't find or create CDE widgets  dir
10:51:30,838 ERROR [CdeEngine] Couldn't find or create CDE widgets dir.
Aug 22, 2015 10:51:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Aug 22, 2015 10:51:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory sw-style
Aug 22, 2015 10:51:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory pentaho-style
Aug 22, 2015 10:51:31 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Aug 22, 2015 10:51:31 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Aug 22, 2015 10:51:31 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=1/10  config=null
Aug 22, 2015 10:51:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 12086 ms
```

### Summary of the pentaho.log

```
2015-08-22 10:51:30,440 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.repository2.unified.jcr.sejcr.GuavaCachePoolPentahoJcrSessionFactory] Error obtaining session from cache. Creating one directly instead: javax.jcr.SimpleCredentials@1ea9919
2015-08-22 10:51:30,680 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.util.logging.Logger] misc-org.pentaho.platform.plugin.action.defaultcontent.DefaultContentSystemListener: User not found; nested exception is org.springframework.security.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException: User not found
2015-08-22 10:51:30,730 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.ActionAdapterQuartzJob] ActionAdapterQuartzJob.ERROR_0004 - Action "org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.versionchecker.VersionCheckerAction" failed to run as a quartz job
2015-08-22 10:51:30,731 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.ActionAdapterQuartzJob] ActionAdapterQuartzJob.ERROR_0001 - Property "ActionAdapterQuartzJob-ActionClass" or "ActionAdapterQuartzJob-ActionId" must be set in the job data map
2015-08-22 10:51:30,731 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.ActionAdapterQuartzJob] ActionAdapterQuartzJob.ERROR_0002 - Failed to create an instance of action "unknown"
2015-08-22 10:51:30,818 ERROR [pt.webdetails.cpf.repository.pentaho.unified.PluginRepositoryResourceAccess] Unable to get repository as system.
2015-08-22 10:51:30,821 ERROR [pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.extapi.FileHandler] Couldn't find or create CDE .  dir
2015-08-22 10:51:30,824 ERROR [pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.CdeEngine] Couldn't find or create CDE base dir.
2015-08-22 10:51:30,824 ERROR [pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.extapi.FileHandler] Couldn't find or create CDE components  dir
2015-08-22 10:51:30,826 ERROR [pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.CdeEngine] Couldn't find or create CDE components dir.
2015-08-22 10:51:30,826 ERROR [pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.extapi.FileHandler] Couldn't find or create CDE styles  dir
2015-08-22 10:51:30,827 ERROR [pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.CdeEngine] Couldn't find or create CDE styles dir.
2015-08-22 10:51:30,827 ERROR [pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.extapi.FileHandler] Couldn't find or create CDE templates  dir
2015-08-22 10:51:30,828 ERROR [pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.CdeEngine] Couldn't find or create CDE templates dir.
2015-08-22 10:51:30,828 ERROR [pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.extapi.FileHandler] Couldn't find or create CDE widgets  dir
2015-08-22 10:51:30,829 ERROR [pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.CdeEngine] Couldn't find or create CDE widgets dir.
2015-08-22 10:51:30,829 ERROR [pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.extapi.FileHandler] Couldn't find or create CDE .  dir
2015-08-22 10:51:30,830 ERROR [pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.CdeEngine] Couldn't find or create CDE base dir.
2015-08-22 10:51:30,831 ERROR [pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.extapi.FileHandler] Couldn't find or create CDE components  dir
2015-08-22 10:51:30,831 ERROR [pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.CdeEngine] Couldn't find or create CDE components dir.
2015-08-22 10:51:30,832 ERROR [pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.extapi.FileHandler] Couldn't find or create CDE styles  dir
2015-08-22 10:51:30,833 ERROR [pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.CdeEngine] Couldn't find or create CDE styles dir.
2015-08-22 10:51:30,835 ERROR [pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.extapi.FileHandler] Couldn't find or create CDE templates  dir
2015-08-22 10:51:30,836 ERROR [pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.CdeEngine] Couldn't find or create CDE templates dir.
2015-08-22 10:51:30,836 ERROR [pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.extapi.FileHandler] Couldn't find or create CDE widgets  dir
2015-08-22 10:51:30,838 ERROR [pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.CdeEngine] Couldn't find or create CDE widgets dir.
```

Comment: Hey did you solved this issue?